# How to fix Sonarqube "Rename this file" code smell that contained in _app.js in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, sonarqube

I created an example Next.js application using `npx create-next-app`. After sonarqube scan, there is 1 code smell appeared that says "*Default export names and file names should match*" [(related link)](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-3317). But since **_app.js** file is a special file for the Next.js framework I can't rename it and can't solve that code smell. How can I fix this code smell?

[image]

Comment: Can't you ignore/suppress that specific rule for that file/line?

Answer (score 0):

To extend what @JulioMalves said, this is how I set up the ignore rule on SonarQube's admin interface.[image]